# Divide a string by a number

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get it so the UserDefaults string (which will always be a number) that is currently saved is able to be divided by, for example, 100, and presented on a label? The following is what I currently have.

```
 let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "time")
 self.TimeLabel.text = "\(savedTime)"
```

Comment: savedTime is a number ? and you want to assign it to a label ?

Comment: No, string is not a number. It is a string. If it contains digits it is still a string not a number. Once you understand the difference, things would be easier. And if you want regular division you need to convert your string to i.e. integer first.

Comment: @Morimaka, you're asking for help, so I'm not sure why you're replying to someone sarcastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just store your `"time"` key that *"will always be a number"* as an Integer in the first place?

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourIntegerTime, forKey: "time")
```

And then access it later with:

```
let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "time")
self.TimeLabel.text = "\(savedTime/100)"
```

---

**As, from the Developer [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer):**

`func integer(forKey defaultName: String) -> Int`

"This method automatically coerces certain values into equivalent integer values (if one can be determined). The Boolean value true becomes 1 and false becomes 0. A floating point number becomes the greatest integer that‘s less than that number (for example, 2.67 becomes 2). **A string that represents an integer becomes the equivalent integer (for example “123“ becomes 123**)."